# Response time query comparison in postgresql/postgis

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I measure the response time of a spatiotemporal query in two different setups.

a) I have a single instance that I have installed PostgreSQL with postGIS extension

b) I have 5 instances (1 master, 3 slaves, 1 client for pgpool II) - pgpool II replication.

My query is:

```
startTW = time.time()
fetchinTW = """SELECT col.vessel_hash,ST_X(col.the_geom) AS long, ST_Y(col.the_geom) AS lat
                FROM samplecol AS col
                WHERE col.timestamp >='2016-06-10T00:00:00.000Z' and col.timestamp <= '2016-07-10:00:00.000Z' """

cursor.execute(fetchinTW)
end_query3 = time.time()
print "Time to execute query: ", end_query3 - start_TW
```

In the results I see that the response time in a) setup is smaller than in b).

a setup -> Response Time: 45,3456 seconds

b setup -> Response Time: 28,4658 seconds

Before I ran the experiments I thought that the response time would be greater in case of pgpool II replication (b setup) than in a and the reason is that the data are replicated between the nodes for availability and fault tolerance and the pgpool II would choose the node to send the query and this have an overhead. For a single node the case is more simple so I thought that the response time would be better (a setup).

Can anyone explain this behavior? Or have an idea why this happens?

Comment: i'm not sure pgpool overhead would be almost 20 seconds faster. Are the tables the same, indexes and content. Are they both vacuumed ?

Comment: All are the same with exactly the same setup. Setup b with pgpool II is almost 20 seconds faster.

Comment: Can you check if the tables are in both environment properly indexed? Are the tables partitioned in any of these setups?

Comment: btw: could you add to your question a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for both environments?

Comment: The tables is properly indexes, yes. You mean in case b if the tables are partitioned right? I have one table that replicated in slaves. The master and the 3 slaves have exactly the same data.

Comment: I take it this is performed using Psycopg2? perhaps there is a cache being used in the pgpool case ? The feeling is this is due to differences in your tables not your set up.

Comment: Yes, the experiments are performed using psycopg2. The tables are the same. So, in order to understand, you also expect that the response time would be slower in case of pgpool ?

Comment: @JimJones I have not that possibility now because b setup was ran in amazon and now I have not the machines. Have you an idea for this behavior?  You also believe that the response time must be slower in case of pgpool?

Comment: not necessarily slower just not such a big difference. If one is in Amazon, what hardware is the other run on? Amazon RDS? have better processing power behind it than in case 'a' ?

Comment: The other is again in amazon with exactly the same setup (cores, ram, etc). Exactly the same machine. You say "not necessarily slower". Why? I dont understand the reason for this.

Comment: @Antonis "__Parallel Query__ Using the parallel query feature, data can be split among multiple servers, so that a query can be executed on all the servers concurrently, reducing the overall execution time. Parallel query works best when searching large-scale data." from http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.3.2/doc/pgpool-en.html

Comment: My guess is that the query is being ran in parallel in your 3 slaves, therefore reducing the execution time.

Comment: The data are replicated between the master and the slaves. So you think that when I run the query the same query splits between the 4 nodes. The results are gathered in one single node?

Comment: I think that you are right. Here is another answer: http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page . I f you want post an answer to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the expected behavior. According to the [`documentation`](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.3.2/doc/pgpool-en.html), pgpool-II's parallel query feature allows queries to be split in different servers:

> **Load Balance**
>
> If a database is replicated(because running in either replication mode
>   or master/slave mode), performing a SELECT query on any server will
>   return the same result. pgpool-II takes advantage of the replication
>   feature in order to reduce the load on each PostgreSQL server. It does
>   that by distributing SELECT queries among available servers, improving
>   the system's overall throughput. In an ideal scenario, read
>   performance could improve proportionally to the number of PostgreSQL
>   servers. Load balancing works best in a scenario where there are a lot
>   of users executing many read-only queries at the same time.
>
> **Parallel Query**
>
> Using the parallel query feature, data can be split among multiple
>   servers, so that a query can be executed on all the servers
>   concurrently, reducing the overall execution time. Parallel query
>   works best when searching large-scale data.

Here is a list of the config parameters for the [`parallel mode`](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.3.2/doc/pgpool-en.html#parallel) feature.